# Opening bean declared in Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mocking, spock

Recently I encountered strange problem with Spring, Kotlin and Spock. I have very simple project (spring-boot, spring-web). I have one `Controller` with few `Bean`s injected to this `Controller`. Everything works just fine. Problem is in test. I am not able to mock any of those `Bean`s. `kotlin-spring`/`kotlin-allopen` does not add `open` signature to beans defined in `Configuration` class. On the other hand if I change this declaration to `@Component` everything works fine.

Here is my `build.gradle.kts` plugin listing

```
plugins {
    id("idea")
    id("groovy")
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.springframework.cloud.contract") version "2.2.5.RELEASE"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.21"
}
```

This is error message:

```
Caused by: org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock for class *** because Java mocks cannot mock final classes. If the code under test is written in Groovy, use a Groovy mock.
```

I know that it says that I can use `GroovyMock` but I wanted to design my base class in test and I wanted to use `@TestConfiguration` class. So to mock those classes I wanted to use `DetachedMockFactory`.

Is there a way to configure Spock to be able to mock final classes from Kotlin? Or is there a way to tell `kotlin-spring`/`kotlin-allopen` to open classes defined as beans in `Configuration` class?

**Edit:**

My example project is here:
https://github.com/czyzniek/bank/tree/with-spock

Comment: Would you mind providing a complete sample project on GitHub? I don't speak Kotlin or Gradle, but if I have something to work with I might be able to help. I know at least 3 different tools you can use from Spock in order to dynamically unfinalise final classes and methods during class-loading (one of them written by myself) and have used all of them before from Maven, so you should also be able to use them from Gradle. The Groovy mock option mentioned in the error message does not apply, though, because your code under test is not written in Groovy.

Comment: You might want to try a new Spock extension that de-finalizes classes https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable

Comment: Also you can configure the allopen plugin to open additional annotations https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin

Comment: The spock-mockable extension is one of the 3 tools I had in mind, yes. Maybe this information is enough for the OP already. If it is not and I can see the sample project, I am still willing to help in a more in-depth fashion.

Comment: Thanks for comments! @kriegaex I edited my question with my project. Regarding spock-mockable I was not able to make it work with my setup. All I got was:


org.spockframework.runtime.SpockExecutionException: Unable to redefined classes: [class pl.sii.bank.accounting.domain.FetchAccountBalanceUseCase]


Any ideas why?

Comment: Not without a sample project, as requested earlier. But you can try and use my tool [Sarek](https://github.com/SarekTest/Sarek) which is still kind of undocumented except for a test suite showing how to use it. Option 1: Add `dev.sarek:sarek-spock-extension:1.0-SNAPSHOT` as a test dependency and use the full Sarek mock framework which the unfinaliser is just a small part of. Option 2: Use `dev.sarek:sarek-unfinal:1.0-SNAPSHOT` in combination with `-javaagent:/path/to/sarek-unfinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in order to just use the unfinaliser with Spock or any other test framework.

Comment: The Sarek unfinaliser will remove `final` from all classes and methods during class-loading, there is not need for extra annotations like with spock-mockable. Sorry I have not published a Sarek 1.0 release on Maven Central, but I had to interrupt development several months ago due to my work. The tool is feature-complete though and definitely the unfinaliser is. Sarek just does so much more and I wanted to improve it more, but you can just ignore the rest for now, even though it works nicely.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed that you published a project on GitHub. Somehow I just focused on your question before. I will take a look and try to help you with the other tool. Meanwhile you can take a look at mine.

Comment: OMG, I hate Gradle! Every new project I clone is downloading the world from Maven Central. Why does it not use a central local repository like Maven does, ideally the very same one? I am sure I can configure that somehow, but I am a Maven user because I do not like scripted builds. So this can take a long time until the downloads are finished, before I can even start to build and run your project.

Comment: Maybe just add mavenLocal() to repositories part in build.gradle.kts ;)

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot help you fix the *spock-mockable* problem, maybe you want to ask the author for help. Recently I fixed a Maven issue in that project already, but now it seems like there is a ByteBuddy issue, trying to redefine an already loaded class which is impossible in the JVM. I am sure the maintainer can help you with that.

Meanwhile, like I suggested in a previous comment, switching to [Sarek](https://github.com/SarekTest/Sarek) solves the problem, though. I created a corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/czyzniek/bank/pull/1) for you.

For now it uses the full Sarek agent, which is the default. If you add `sarek-unfinal` as a dependency instead of `sarek` <strike>and also make sure that you set the system property `dev.sarek.agent.type=unfinal`</strike> in your Gradle configuration for Spock tests, you can use the smaller unfinal agent without the rest of the Sarek functionality instead. <strike>As a Gradle noob I do not know how to configure that, though.</strike>

**Update:** There is no more need for the additional system property mentioned above. The latest Sarek snapshot auto-detects the unfinal agent (or any other of the 4 types of Sarek agents) when it is on the class path. I know you have decided to use spock-mockable, but I want to keep this answer up to date for reference. See [this diff](https://github.com/czyzniek/bank/compare/master...kriegaex:with-spock) for what the pull request would look like now, especially [this simple commit](https://github.com/kriegaex/bank/commit/2b4b819).

Please let me know if you have any issues using the snapshot version for now. If this is a commercial project and you need to build a release in which snapshot versions are forbidden at some point, I can publish an 1.0 or maybe a 0.8 or whatever on Maven Central. For now I just added the Maven Central snapshot repository (Sonatype OSS) to your build.

Comment: **Update:** I added some info about Sarek agent type auto detection for reference, just in case anyone will find this answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help everybody! @kriegaex your solution works like a charm, thanks for that!

Regarding `spock-mockable`, I talked with author of this library and he figured out why `spock-mockable` could not work with my setup ([GH issue](https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable/issues/9)). It was because of `spock-spring` extension. The root cause is that `spock-spring` extension was loaded before `spock-mockable`. When Spring/Spock wanted to create mocks from `@TestConfiguration` class it couldn't, because `kotlin-spring` plugin does not open classes declared as beans in a `@Configuration` class and `spock-mockable` was not loaded at this time. joke changed the way his extension is loaded, so right now both solutions `spock-mockable` and `sarek` work.

I believe that concludes my problem ;)